# How to externalize TestNG/Junit tests (run them sparatly) from a Maven project?

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, testng

In my project i separated all integration(junit) and selenium(testng) tests into a maven module. The tests are executed via maven on the parent module. so before integration/selenium testing the main module is built and some properties are set. (jenkins runs all tests on every build)

now i need to run this module's tests independent from main module (especially the selenium tests must be executed externally). how to achieve that? is there a "jar-with-dependencies" for tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you already run `mvn install` on your main module, you can just run `mvn test` command (or whatever command you use to run your Selenium test) on your integration test module.

Comment: the problem is: the both modules share many configuration items (besides their relationship), so mvn test on test module doesn't work at the moment (installing main module isn't enough). the question is: is their a way to run tests without maven? or is there a maven plugin/goal to run on parent that creates a runable test artefact?

Comment: Normally it is enough to declare dependency on your main module, but you'll have to provide a more specific example in regards to your shared configuration. In worst case you can declare path to your configuration in test module using relative path to your main project.

Comment: besides plugin versions and some properties both modules share (specified only in parent pom) the parent and hence version, corporate pom, groupId. My problem is: What are minimum requirements to run only one module. At the moment i have to install (beside maven) the corporate pom, the parent pom and the main module to be able to run the tests. Is there a way to give the test module an alternative configuration (for the external environment) - probably via a profile - that reduces the requirements (no corporate pom, no parent pom) or in best case no main module and no mvn (one jar for all).

Comment: You can choose the parent for your test module. It doesn't have to be your corporate parent pom. On the other hand, the parents are not changing very often (or there is something wrong there), so it may actually not be an issue. Anyways, using some sort of CI server would help with installing your other modules too.

Comment: i want to run selenium tests in two different environments: ours (corporate) and in customers environment (is it possible to change parent by profile?). there is probably also a maven infrastructure but i want to minimize the requirements for this second environment (an executable jar has only one: java).

Comment: you can't change the parent, but you can specify different environment-related properties in two separate profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `dependency` under `dependencies` in your `pom`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Add the following under `build` in your `pom.xml`

```
<testSourceDirectory>D:\eclipse_workspace\Utils_project\test_filelister</testSourceDirectory>
```

Add the following in plugins

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.11</version>
<configuration>
    <test>**/*.java</test>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @khmarbaise That's true, but I felt it would be easier to understand